# WebAssembly compiler error: undefined symbol when compile with a external library

Tags: c++, qt, webassembly, emscripten

Goodmorning everyone,
i am starting to work with webassembly.
I describe my problem:
I have created a simple static library (called TinyLib), and I want to use in my WebAssembly project.
TinyLib contains contructor, destructor and a numeric attribute.
The WebAssembly project (called TestWidget) is a simple dialog with a label inside where I write through the TinyLib library.
My intent is to write the value of attribute into label.
I tried to compile both projects as Desktop mode projects (Desktop Qt 5.15.0 MinGW 64-bit) with success.
I compiled TinyLib with Qt 5.15.0 WebAssembly and generate libTinyLib.a lib
I compiled TestWidget, alon and the project run!
Now if I try to compile both projects in WebAssembly mode (TestWidget use TinyLib), while compiling TestWidget, I get this error message:

error: undefined symbol: _ZN7TinyLibC1Ev
warning: Link with -s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED to get more information on undefined symbols
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS = 0
error: undefined symbol: _ZN7TinyLibD1Ev

I tried to search on the web but without success.
In this forum I found the following thread:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/115660/add-static-library
but it didn't help me.

Have you also had the same problem? And how did you solve it?

O.S. Windoows 10 Pro; Qt 5.15.0; EMCC 1.39.8

my pro file is

TestWidget.pro

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan (QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c ++ 11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE = 0x060000 # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    dialog.cpp

HEADERS += \
    dialog.h

FORMS += \
    dialog.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:! android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
! isEmpty (target.path): INSTALLS += target

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../TinyLib/build-TinyLib-Qt_5_15_0_WebAssembly-Debug/ -lTinyLib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../TinyLib/TinyLib
DEPENDPATH + = $$PWD/../../TinyLib/TinyLib
```

Answer (score 0):

after contact the qt support, they suggest me to replace

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../TinyLib/build-TinyLib-Qt_5_15_0_WebAssembly-Debug/ -lTinyLib
```

with

```
wasm:LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../TinyLib/build-TinyLib-Qt_5_15_0_WebAssembly-Debug/ -lTinyLib
```